# imshow with non-orthogonal axes (i.e. parallelogram )

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2D array of data sampled along two vectors non-orthogonal a, b

a = |a|.( cos(alfa), sin(alfa) )

b = |b|.( cos(beta), sin(beta) )

(i.e not along orthogonal cartesian direction x, y)

I would like to plot this data un-distorted (i.e. as parallelogram instead of rectangle)

is there any function to do that in matplotlib?

I need it for plotting data like this (c, f , i)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how it should be done, but something like [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_demo.html) may help.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an affine transform as in this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/demo_affine_image.html),

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms

def get_image():
    from scipy import misc
    Z = misc.imread('31271907.jpg')
    return Z

# Get image
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
Z = get_image()

# image skew
im = ax.imshow(Z, interpolation='none', origin='lower',
                 extent=[-2, 4, -3, 2], clip_on=True)
im._image_skew_coordinate = (3, -2)

plt.show()
```

Which uses the image

[image]

and turns it into,

[image]

Comment: Hi, it is very useful, I just don't understand what `_image_skew_coordinate = (3, -2)` exactly mean. I would expect something like 2x2 affine transform matrix, but this is just one vector which tilts both x and y axes

Comment: Hi @ProkopHapala, the `_image_skew_coordinate` has no documentation as it is for "internal use", so the use in the linked example seems a bit like a hack. From the Affine transform docs it looks possible the two numbers specify shear angles along the x- and y-axes, respectively, in radians (see http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D.skew).

Comment: I don't think it is angle in radians since the number is round (integer) ... I think it is simply the coordinate of one of the skewed corners ... the second corner is assumed to be symmetric